# nfc reader doesnt work with google ArCore activated on android

Tags: nfc, arcore

an nfc reader doesnt work with google ArCore activated on android, or the android camera activated.

I tried to put an NFC card on a cell phone with the google ArCore app and it did not read the NFCs, or when the cell phone had the camera on. NFC only works with the camera, or ArCore turned off

How to fix it? thanks

Comment: Probably the same reason as https://stackoverflow.com/q/76520588/2373819