# Can I use NFC Scanner and QR scanner simultaneously in my Java app?

Tags: java, nfc, qr-code, scanning

I'm trying to make an application in Java that will handle qr Scanning from my camera and also Nfc scanning . I've seen that android 11 bring problem that when I will open the camera then the NFC ability to scan will get disabled. Anyone know if this issue trully exist? And how can I solve it to make them both work together at the same time?

Comment: Ive already made an implementation that makes the problem exist. Ive implemented a camera section at my mobile screen so when i open it and scan a QR Code then it shows me the result. Also Ive implemented the NFC section that when I scan an NFC also shows me the info. The problem comes when I include both of them at my layout, then only the QR scanner is playing and the NFC is not recognisable at all from my logs

Comment: That information would already improve the question. You can improve it even further by showing the code that causes the problem.

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76520588/2373819 It's seems a hardware issue.